# extract values (text) from html table using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, extract

Hello I want ot extract text and insert them into a DB table
this is the code of product description

```
> <table class="AttrDTable"><!--@HeaderPlacehoder--><tr
> class="AttrDRow"><td class="AttrDTypeName">Cod produs (Part number)
> original</td><td class="AttrDValue">5014702023309</td></tr><tr
> class="AttrDAltRow"><td class="AttrDTypeName">Nume produs</td><td
> class="AttrDValue">Pricing gun, single row (8 numeric characters),
> black</td></tr><tr class="AttrDRow"><td
> class="AttrDTypeName">Producator</td><td class="AttrDValue">Avery
> Zweckform</td></tr><tr class="AttrDAltRow"><td
> class="AttrDTypeName">Clasa produsului</td><td
> class="AttrDValue">Aparatură pentru
> birou</td></tr></td></tr><!--@FooterPlacehoder--></table>
```

I am interested only the values from `<td class="AttrDTypeName">` and `<td class="AttrDValue">` those values I will enter into database

I have made for html with `<br>` and `<strong>` values this is the code

```
$rand=explode("&lt;br&gt;",$descriere);
    for ($i=0;$i<count($rand);$i++)
        if ($rand[$i]!='')
        {
            $element=explode(": &lt;/strong&gt;",$rand[$i]);
            $element[0]=str_replace("&lt;strong&gt;","",$element[0]);
            $element[1]=str_replace("&nbsp;","",$element[1]);

            echo $element[0]."---".$element[1]."##"."<br>";


            $exista=mysqli_query($conexiune, "SELECT * FROM oc_attribute_description WHERE name='".$element[0]."'") or die(mysqli_error($conexiune));
            if  (!mysqli_num_rows($exista))
                {
                    mysqli_query($conexiune, "INSERT INTO oc_attribute (attribute_group_id) VALUES ('4')");
                    $id_attr=mysqli_insert_id($conexiune);
                    //inserez descriere atribut nou in tabela
                    mysqli_query($conexiune, "INSERT INTO oc_attribute_description (attribute_id, language_id, name) VALUES ('".$id_attr."', '2', '".$element[0]."')")  or die(mysqli_error($conexiune));

                }
            $atribut=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conexiune, "SELECT attribute_id FROM oc_attribute_description WHERE name='".$element[0]."'"));

            $exista2=mysqli_query($conexiune, "SELECT * FROM oc_product_attribute WHERE product_id='".$product_id."' AND attribute_id='".$atribut[0]."'") or die(mysqli_error($conexiune));
            if  (!mysqli_num_rows($exista2))
                {
                    mysqli_query($conexiune, "INSERT INTO oc_product_attribute (product_id, attribute_id, language_id, text) VALUES ('".$product_id."', '".$atribut[0]."', '2', '".$element[1]."')")  or die(mysqli_error($conexiune));

                }
            else
                mysqli_query($conexiune, "UPDATE oc_product_attribute SET text='".$element[1]."' WHERE product_id='".$product_id."' AND attribute_id='".$atribut[0]."'")  or die(mysqli_error($conexiune));
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Check out https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser . Seems as it would help you out here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple html dom. It is the easiest and fastest dom extractor for php. Here I am writing some code as per your requirement. I am assuming that your html contain data is in uss.html. So, here is a simple code

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = file_get_html("uss.html");
$data = $html->find('td[class=AttrDTypeName]');
$data1 = $html->find('td[class=AttrDValue]');

echo "Your data from, td class="AttrDTypeName"<br><br>";

foreach($data as $val)
{
    echo $val->innertext."<br><br>";
}

echo "Your data from, td class="AttrDValue"<br><br>"

foreach($data1 as $val1)
{
    echo $val1->innertext."<br><br>";
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer, my data is in a database table under column "Description" and the val and val1 that i extract i want to insert them into another table called attribute with nam=val value=val1

Comment: @coZmoXimo Do you want to parse data from `Description` and than insert it into another table, right?

Comment: yes, but the column description is also in a table they are in the same database

Comment: this is the code from where i extract the description.
 $caut=mysqli_query($conexiune, "SELECT * FROM aa_produse WHERE activ='1'") or die(mysqli_error($conexiune));
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($caut))
     {
      $product_id=$row['cod_intern'];
      $descriere=$row['descriere'];
      
      echo $product_id."<br>";

Comment: @coZmoXimo in my answer, `$val` and `$val1` are your desire value, insert it in your table, what it the problem than.